# How to count identical rows?

Tags: talend

I have rows with years in a csv file as follows:

```
2009
2010
2010
```

After processing them, I want an output as follows:

```
2009:1
2010:2
```

How do I get the number of identical rows?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. And specify your coding language.

Comment: What coding language are you talking about? I already told you this is a tool called talend. Check the tag

Comment: Please read the tag and then answer. Don't just answer for the sake of answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got the answer in taggregaterow. I created duplicate rows and then grouped using one and counted the other.

I duplicated the year rows into year1 and year2. Then I selected the option in the following[image]

Comment: Consider editing your question and answer so that it might be more useful as a general example on using Talend to count duplicate values to better help other people who may have your issue in the future.